# Detecting transparency/glass clarity with openCV

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I'm working on a project right now in which a key part relies on a glass slide being clean and fully transparent after having a film adhered to it.

By eye it is obvious when the the film has been well applied, since there are no cloudy sections or bubbles. Is there a good way to measure this 'clarity' with openCV?

I'm in the fortuante position that imaging of the glass can be carried out in a controlled environment; For example I can control the focus and anything that might appear behind the glass. I wondered if I could use this to try to pick out a known pattern and from that somehow determine clarity. Additionally, it may be helpful to be able to detect cracks in the glass, and I can control the lighting which may assist in illuminating fractures.

Has anyone done anything similar before, and could point me towards some reading or examples?

Comment: It might be possible to do via [thresholding](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.1/d7/d4d/tutorial_py_thresholding.html) but without seeing your images I couldn't say for certain, you may need to additional post processing.

Comment: I'd like to emphasize how important it is to get your post right. you get *one* glance from most visitors. most won't bother checking back after you've made edits.

Comment: can you post an image?